# Running issue when buid defenation execute using microsoft host agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I execute the build definition using Microsoft agent, the below error is reflecting
Error: The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. The current position in the queue: 1
The build execution took days and it is bonded. Can someone please help me to run out of this issue?
Scenarios I tried:

1. reinstalling the self-hosted agent and reconfigure the agent again.
2. I am trying with Microsoft agent "Azure pipelines"

Answer (score 0):

> Running issue when buid defenation execute using microsoft host agent?

If your pipeline queues but never gets an agent, check the following items:

- [Parallel job limits - no available agents or you have hit your free limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#parallel-job-limits---no-available-agents-or-you-have-hit-your-free-limits)
- [You don't have enough concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#you-dont-have-enough-concurrency)
- [Your job may be waiting for approval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#your-job-may-be-waiting-for-approval)
- [All available agents are in use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#all-available-agents-are-in-use)
- [Demands that don't match the capabilities of an agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#demands-that-dont-match-the-capabilities-of-an-agent)
- [Check Azure DevOps status for a service degradation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#check-azure-devops-status-for-a-service-degradation)

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#pipeline-queues-but-never-gets-an-agent) for some more details.

**Note:** Please also check if Microsoft Hosted Pool `Azure Pipelines' are stuck on builds that you cancelled and deleted.

If above not help you, please share more info about your definition to help us to find the reason for this issue:

Agent pool info:

[image]

Execution plan info:

[image]

Parallel jobs info (And click the link View in-progress jobs):

[image]